# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'set'

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn python for data science application and signed up for a course. I am doing the exercises and got stuck even though my answer is the same as the one in the answer key.

I'm basically trying to add two new items to a dictionary with the following piece of code:

```
# Create a new key-value pair for 'Inner London'
location_dict['Inner London'] = location_dict['Camden'] + location_dict['Southwark']

# Create a new key-value pair for 'Outer London'
location_dict['Outer London'] = location_dict['Brent'] + location_dict['Redbridge']
```

but when I run it I am getting a `TypeError`.

Comment: When trying to learn python, be sure you know how to interpret errors and exceptions. Like in this case, either you want to append values in this `set`, or you want to add two numbers together, in which case you need to realize `location_dict['Camden']` is NOT a number, but a `set`

Comment: To combine sets you either need to use `setA.union(setB)` or `setA | setB`.

Comment: Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) In this case, it would be helpful to know the structure of your dictionary to give you an advice, how to achieve your desired output. I.e. what are the data type(s) in your dictionary.

Comment: What are the values of each of the parts of the sum you are trying to do? Do they exist, are they valid?

Answer (score 5):

I had a list in there with the sets I think that was what was throwing the error I just converted the list to a set and joined them with .union. Thank you @Adelin, @Bilkokuya, @ Piinthesky, and @Kurast for you're quick responses and input!

Answer (score 3):

for union of sets you can use `|`

```
location_dict['Camden'] | location_dict['Southwark']
```